# IllegalStateException: Duplicate parameter types in Play + SecureSocial

Tags: java, playframework, ebean, securesocial

I am using [Activator 1.2.3](https://typesafe.com/activator) and SecureSocial in the latest SNAPSHOT version (db46f2c3db784f3596ddd407075c222952d08129).

Currently I am trying to implement the user store in a relational database using Play's Ebean. I found that [this SO anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16093023/play-securesocial-persistance-with-java) does not apply anymore. Therefore, I am rolling my own implementation. Token store was quite simple, however I am having problems with storing the user profiles.

This is my entity:

```
@Entity
public class DbUser extends Model {

  @EmbeddedId
  public DbUserId id;

  @ManyToOne
  public DbUser mainProfile;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "mainProfile")
  public Set<DbUser> profiles;

  public String firstName;
  public String lastName;
  public String fullName;
  public String email;
  public String avatarUrl;

  @Constraints.Required
  public AuthenticationMethod authMethod;

  public OAuth1Info oAuth1Info;
  public OAuth2Info oAuth2Info;

  public PasswordInfo passwordInfo;

  ...
}
```

This is the ID entity:

```
@Embeddable
public class DbUserId {

  @Constraints.Required
  public String providerId;

  @Constraints.Required
  public String userId;
  ...
}
```

*Disclaimer: I understand this is probably not the ideal way to go, translating between this and SecureSocial's Option'ed fields is painful to say the least.*

I have adapted the `InMemoryUserService` to work with these entities and even guessed how the `doLink()` method should work. I am, however, having problems with running this. Right before the new evolution should be applied I get the following error:

```
[info] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:h2:mem:play
[error] c.a.e.s.d.p.DeployCreateProperties - Error with models.DbUser field:oAuth1Info
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate parameter types in public securesocial.core.OAuth1Info(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.type.reflect.ImmutableMetaFactory.scoreConstructors(ImmutableMetaFactory.java:106) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.type.reflect.ImmutableMetaFactory.createImmutableMeta(ImmutableMetaFactory.java:21) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.type.DefaultTypeManager.recursiveCreateScalarDataReader(DefaultTypeManager.java:185) ~[avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.DeployCreateProperties.createProp(DeployCreateProperties.java:317) [avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
    at com.avaje.ebeaninternal.server.deploy.parse.DeployCreateProperties.createProp(DeployCreateProperties.java:345) [avaje-ebeanorm-3.3.4.jar:na]
```

My presumption is that the OAuthInfo's and the Password info are simply not @Entities, and that I will have to make my own entities and map between them. However, I'd still like to understand this error...